# Cannot assign value type mismatch swift

Tags: ios, swift, option-type, weak

I have the following code snippet.

```
 camera.onDeviceChange = { [weak self] (camera: LLSimpleCamera!, device: AVCaptureDevice!) -> Void in
      print("Device changed.")
 }
```

This used to work fine in Swift 2, but now I am getting the following error message:

> Cannot assign value of type '(LLSimpleCamera!, AVCaptureDevice!) -> Void' to type '((LLSimpleCamera?, AVCaptureDevice?) -> Void)!'

Not really sure how to change this, I tried matching the type by changing the ! to optionals and then adding ! after the void, however this didn't work.

Comment: try  `camera.onDeviceChange = { [weak self] (camera, device) -> Void in`

Comment: thanks, post it as an answer and I'll accept :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error suggest type mismatch that means `LLSimpleCamera! != LLSimpleCamera?` .. there is no need to define type. .. you can use it something like

```
camera.onDeviceChange = { [weak self] (camera, device) -> Void in
   print("Device changed.")
}
```